# setting custom subdomain with github pages while domain may point somewhere else

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I have a custom domain - example.com. 
I need to set it up such that the subdomain 'premium' (premium.example.com) points to github pages to a certain repository. but the apex domain (example.com) and the 'www' subdomain(www.example.com) points to some other server, maybe a wordpress based server.

I'm confused over these two aspects, on which one to set in my DNS spec:

1. set the 'A' record in cPanel for 'premium.example.com' to point to github servers (185.199.108.153, 185.199.109.153, 185.199.110.153, 185.199.111.153).
2. set the 'CNAME' record in cPanel for 'premium.example.com' to point to my github url (myuser.github.io).

could you please explain which of the two can be used to set up my subdomain? also what configuration to set for my apex and 'www' custom domains?

Answer (score 0):

**It should be the `CNAME` record.**

You can add a `CNAME` record and point `premium` to `myuser.github.io`. It's specified in the [GitHub Pages document](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-a-custom-subdomain) Also, you need to configure `premium.example.com` as the custom domain in the GitHub repository settings page([document](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-or-removing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site)).

`CNAME` is used to resolve your domain name to another one. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record):

> A Canonical Name record (abbreviated as CNAME record) is a type of resource record in the Domain Name System (DNS) which maps one domain name (an alias) to another (the Canonical Name.)

Comment: Ok. But how would we then configure the apex domain (example.com) to point to some other server ? Do we need to keep the 'A' records of apex domain pointed to the four github IP addresses ?

Comment: The question is pointing apex domain to some other server. So you need to make ‘A’ record point to that ‘other’ server, not github’s IP address.